# Can I use a if statement inside the Set-ADUser cmdlet to check if a column is null before updating AD with the information from that column?

Tags: powershell, csv, import, active-directory, updating

I have edited my question based on responses in the comments below.

I am writing a script that updates Active Directory from a csv file. The file contains many columns and some of them are blank which means I have to skip those columns. Problem is I have no idea ahead of time which columns are blank and which are not and it changes from file to file. The script will run every half an hour pulling data from a HR system to update the AD record with.

The column names in the CSV file do not match the property names in AD so to accommodate for that I created a custom object where I basically define properties whose names do match AD property names and assign the values of each column to that object's properties. This should allow me to use splatting to update AD.

The AD object to update is contained in a variable called $CurrentADUser.

The custom object is getting it's values from the CSV record which is read from the CSV file and stored in $CSVUserData - not all the records are here , only one record is in this object at a time so i do not need to loop through every record in the file at this point as this script is written in a different function which is called as the CSV file loops through records.

I cannot seem to get it to work. The script generate no errors but the object's properties do not seem to be recognized by the For each loop that follows it and it just skips the for each loop basically after trying once.

The code  i am using is as follows hopefully someone can spot my error for me

**The Description variable is set by combining the values of $CSVUserData.JobTitle and $CSVUserData.Department  and since AD requires a AD object to insert into the Manager property and not a string this is also manipulated outside of this declaration. the rest come straight from the CSV record**

```
$ADObjectToUpdate = [PSCustomobject]@{
    GivenName = $CSVUserData.FirstName 
    Surname = $CSVUserData.LastName
    Description = $DescriptionString
    Title =$CSVUserData.JobTitle
    Department = $CSVUserData.Department
    Manager = $ADManager **<- this is an AD object**
    Company = $CSVUserData.Company
    EmployeeID = $CSVUserData.EmployeeNumber
    StreetAddress = $CSVUserData.WorkAddress
    City = $CSVUserData.City
    State = $CSVUserData.State
    PostalCode = $CSVUserData.Zip
    Country = $CSVUserData.Country
    Office = $CSVUserData.Location
    LogonWorkstations = $CSVUserData.WorkstationLocation
    EmailAddress = $CSVUserData.EmailAddress
}
$setSplat = @{}
ForEach($_ in $ADObjectToUpdate.PSObject.Properties) 
{
  If(-not([string]::IsnullOrWhiteSpace($_.Value)))
  {
      $setSplat[$_.Name] = $_.Value
  }
}

Set-ADUser -Identity $CurrentADUser @setSplat
```

I want to say thanks to everyone who left me a comment, some were extremely useful for setting me on this approach

Comment: Do the column names on your CSV match exactly with the [parameters of `Set-ADUser`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/activedirectory/set-aduser?view=windowsserver2022-ps#parameters) ? If so, you can definitely handle this with splatting in a dynamic manner

Comment: Santiago Squarzon - no they do not, in the example I gave the 'Preferred name' property does not exist in AD, the data is supposed to go into the givenName property but since Preferred Name  is not a required field in our HR system it is often times blank. That's why I chose this as an example of my struggle.

Comment: Please add the list of column names from your CSV and how they correlate with the cmdlet's parameters, I'll show you how you can do it

Comment: Sounds like you might want to have a read about "splatting" (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_splatting?view=powershell-7.3) where you build a hashtable of your parameters - e.g. ```$splat = @{"param1" = "value1"; "param2 = "value2"}; if( $something) { $splat.Add("param3", "value3" }; Set-AdUser @splat```, which is equivalent to ```Set-ADUser -param1 "value1" -param2 "value2" -param3 "value3"``` - that way you can dynamically build a list of parameters to pass to the ```Set-ADUser``` cmdlet...

Comment: A simple way to do it would be to build a hashtable with *all* columns from the csv file with their correct parameter names in the hashtable keys, and then iterate over the keys removing any items that have a null value - the remaining hashtable can then be splatted into ```Set-ADUser```...

Comment: Use a foreach loop to enumerate through rows and then check if column is null : if($row.ColumnName -eq $null)

Comment: Santiago Squarzon
I have added my code to the above question, in the main question.

Comment: You need to clarify what are the CSV column names and how they're mapped to the `Set-ADUser` parameters

Comment: Open your csv file in notepad, copy the first 3 or 4 lines, [edit] your post and paste the copiedlines in so we can see what you actually have as input

Comment: Santiago Squarzon -  Columns in the csv file are as follows: Action, EffectiveStartDate, FirstName, PreferredName, LastName,JobTitle,Department, ManagerUserName, Company,EmployeeNumber, WorkAddress,City,State,Zip,Country,Location,WorkstationLocation,Phone,EmployeeADUserName, WorkEmail - The first column is used to describe what type of changes in AD I am making, it could be 'hire','Rehire','Terminate' and 'change' - the second column is not used. The variable $DescriptionString is built by combining the JobTitle columns with the Department column.

Comment: Theo - sorry, besides the header line the data I am actually dealing with involves actual users and is confidential. My organization would shoot me if I posted such info here (or anywhere actually) - it is a CSV file so all info in it is in string format.

Comment: `$ADObjectToUpdate.PSCustomObject.Propertiesd` should be `$ADObjectToUpdate.PSObject.Properties`

Comment: Santiago Squarzon - thanks a bundle for that- I would have thought to use PSCustomObject as that is what I defined but the PSObject is the ticket - the set-ADUser command is failing now - should the -identity parameter also be in the splat or should i try as is above?

Comment: You still have `$ADObjectToUpdate.PSCustomObject.Properties` in your code, it should be `$ADObjectToUpdate.PSObject.Properties` as stated previously. `-Identity` can be also in the object but not mandatory, you can use `Set-ADUser -Identity $CurrentADUser @setSplat` as you have it right now and it should work

Comment: Santiago Squarzon - edited, thanks again

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to take your script a step further, you could set up a hash table that can be used to correlate the CSV columns with the [`Set-ADUser` paramaters](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/activedirectory/set-aduser?view=windowsserver2022-ps#parameters), on the left-hand side (the hash table Keys) you can put the CSV column names and in the right-hand side (the hash table Values) you would put the parameter name. For instance:

```bash
$map = @{
    FirstName           = 'GivenName'
    LastName            = 'Surname'
    Department          = 'Department'
    JobTitle            = 'Title'
    Company             = 'Company'
    EmployeeNumber      = 'EmployeeID'
    WorkAddress         = 'StreetAddress'
    City                = 'City'
    State               = 'State'
    Zip                 = 'PostalCode'
    Country             = 'Country'
    Location            = 'Office'
    WorkstationLocation = 'LogonWorkstations'
    EmailAddress        = 'EmailAddress'
}
```

This hash table would be at the top of your code, outside the loop, then you can use it's keys to iterate over the object's properties and check if their value is not null or empty:

```bash
foreach($ADObjectToUpdate in Import-Csv path\to\csv) {
    $setSplat = @{}
    # for each key in our correlation table
    foreach($key in $map.Keys) {
        # here we get the value of each property
        # of the csv
        $value = $ADObjectToUpdate.$key
        # then we can check if its not null or empty
        if(-not [string]::IsNullOrWhiteSpace($value)) {
            # and if its not, we can assign it to the splatting hash
            $setSplat[$map[$key]] = $value
        }
    }

    # unclear how these 2 are obtained but here,
    # you would need an additional condition for them
    if($DescriptionString) {
        $setSplat['Description'] = $DescriptionString
    }

    if($ADManager) {
        $setSplat['Manager'] = $ADManager
    }

    # now you need to be certain that there is something to update
    # for this user, for this, check if the `$setSplat` has something in it
    if($setSplat.Keys.Count) {
        # unclear how `$CurrentADUser` is obtained here
        Set-ADUser -Identity $CurrentADUser @setSplat
    }
}
```

Comment: Excellent Thanks a bundle! - Just a quick FYI - The code I wrote is contained in a function that receives the CurrentADUser and the current record in the CSV file as parameters ($CSVUserData). I had to put the setting of AD properties in a seperate function as the main script was getting to long and cumbersome to manage as one large file and since the CSV data needed to be manipulated a little first it seemed to make sense to do it this way. The functions are in a separate file and I use dot sourcing to link it all together.