# Creating an array from a CSV file which may/may not have values each time

Tags: arrays, powershell, csv, null

relatively new to the whole powershell/scripting game but like to think I have enough knowledge to get by. However this one is getting me frustrated. So in my scenario I have a CSV file which contains new users. Now The script I have below works perfectly fine for doing what I need it to do. The problem I have however comes when a field in the CSV file has no value. So for example I have 5 users I want to set the attributes on, however only 3 of them have a manager field that we want to populate.

So lets say I leave the manager field empty in the CSV file then when I run the script it gives me errors trying to run the Set-ADUser command. So my question is, how can I build the array below correctly to allow for one user having an empty manager field but the next user needs that same value populating? Its almost like I need an if command inside the array where I only want to consider the attribute in the array if there is a value in the CSV file. I dont believe you can run if commands inside an array though. Hopefully what I am asking makes sense.

```
$newusers = import-csv "c:\file.csv"

foreach ($newuser in $newusers) {

$userprops = @('')

$manager = Get-ADUser -Identity $newuser.Manager | Select -ExpandProperty distinguishedName

$userprops = @{
extensionAttribute9 = $newuser.extatt9
extensionAttribute11 = $newuser.extatt11
extensionAttribute14 = $newuser.extatt14
description = $newuser.Description
l = $newuser.City
title = $newuser.Title
department = $newuser.Department
c = $newuser.Country
physicalDeliveryOfficeName = $newuser.Office
manager = $manager
}

Get-ADUser -Identity $newuser.SamAccountName | Set-ADUser -Replace $userprops -Confirm:$false

}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75934171/can-i-use-a-if-statement-inside-the-set-aduser-cmdlt-to-check-if-a-column-is-nul/75944037#75944037

Comment: Having read that, it does look like splatting is something I should be looking at. To be honest, never even heard of that concept before.

Comment: The hashtable is only needed if your __CSV columns don't match with the `Set-ADUser` parameters__. If your CSV columns match then you dont need it

Answer (score 0):

Rather than having to mess around with the csv content itself, have you tried altering whether you check for the manager in AD in the first place?

For instance, change the line

```
$manager = Get-ADUser -Identity $newuser.Manager | Select -ExpandProperty distinguishedName
```

to this instead

```
If ($newuser.Manager -ne "")
{
    $manager = Get-ADUser -Identity $newuser.Manager | Select -ExpandProperty distinguishedName
}
else
{
    $manager = ""
}
```

That way IF the csv entry has a Manager entry it will go and retrieve it, if not it will simply set it to "" so nothing is set.

Comment: So I was contemplating something like this, but 2 things I wasnt keen/sure on. Firstly, I would have to add a check like this on around 25 different values which my CSV will contain for many AD attributes. That to me would just make my script massive, and I would have hoped there would be a much neater and efficient way of doing it. The other thing, is even if the $manager = "" value is returned, I will still be trying to pass that to the Set-AdUser command. I was hoping there was a way I could only try and set variables that had values.

Comment: I actually just tried this. I get the below error as soon as I take the manager value out of my CSV file and run it.

Set-ADUser : replace
At C:\Scripts\newo365mailbox.ps1:46 char:48
+ ... countName | Set-ADUser -Replace $dpwprops -Confirm:$false -Add @{prox ...
+                 ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (CN=Jeff xxx,...ncrexx,DC=local:ADUser) [Set-ADUser], ADInvalidOperationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ActiveDirectoryServer:0,Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.Commands.SetADUser

Comment: For further reference.. if I just try and pass the manager value directly on the set-aduser command rather than part of an array, I get the below..

Set-ADUser : Identity info provided in the extended attribute: 'Manager' could not be resolved. Reason: 'Cannot find an object with identity: '' under: 'DC=sxxon,DC=local'.'.

Comment: Last update... I just changed the code to say $manager = $null instead of $manager = "" and this time the script processed fine. So it doesnt like trying to set an empty string, but is fine with setting a null one.

Comment: Can someone explain the difference between the below two snippets of code? The first bit of code works. The second does not and moans about a null value.

    $manager=$null
    Set-ADUser "joe.bloggs" -Manager $manager

    $manager=$null
    $userprops = @{
    manager = $manager
    }
    Set-ADUser -Replace $userprops

Comment: Don't know, but I'd guess that 1) is explicitly expecting a value to be provided when you specify `-manager`, while 2) with `-Replace` is looking at the record as a whole and just replacing those attributes that need changing, so ignores those elements don't require a change.

Comment: This is exactly what I thought it should be doing. And hence my preference to do the -Replace option. However, it just doesnt work using the replace option regardless of if I set the value to "" or set it to $null.